# Show data only from one cluster

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, dbscan

I have a pandas dataframe.

```
input_data = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 5]}
d = pd.DataFrame(data=input_data)

anotherdata= magic(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=anotherdata)
```

I use DBSCAN to cluster `df`.
As result I have `cluster_labels`. Labels can have values from -1 (outlier) to 2 in this case.

I want to have an opportunity to show only data from particular class separately and have an access to initial dataframe `d` by index.

For example, I have an element with index 1 in `input_data`. 
The element is assigned to cluster 0 and there is no other elements of cluster 0.

How can I find this element in `input_data` by index?

Comment: your example can't be run since PCA is not defined, just a heads up

Comment: and from what you're asking it looks like you want `d.loc[1,:]`

Comment: Is it the one from `sklearn`?

Comment: Actually, PCA does not meter, I just edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use

```
d[cluster_labels == 0]
```

Unless your `magic` function changed indexes.